# checking string for double letter in a row

Tags: python, string

I'am trying to create a funtion that returns True if a string has the same letters side by side

Expected Output:
`print(double_letters("Error"))` should return `True` because of `rr`.

```
def double_letters(string):
    
    string_len = len(string) - 1 
    index1 = 0  
    index2 = 1  
    word1 = string[index1, string_len]
    word2 = string[index2, string_len]

    while string_len > 0:
        if word1 != word2:
            index1 += 1
            index2 += 1         #keeps the checked words side by side
            string_len -= 1    
        else:
            return True
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `string[index1, string_len]`?

Comment: I am trying give the string a variable controlled range, so i can go += 1 in the loop, to move on to the next word. Example Error[0] then Error[1] E then r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily compare two consecutive letters in a word using indexes

```
def double_letters(word):
    for i in range (len(word)-1):
        if word[i] == word[i+1]:
            return True
    return False

print(double_letters("Error"))
```

Comment: `flag = True` could be `return True`, to stop the loop at the first occurrence.

Comment: Above the loop i am trying to use string[0] string[1]... and so on to check single letters. But i just use variables for the numbers to get contoll of the checked word. Is it even possible to add a second parameter like string[1, 2] ?

Comment: @Marco I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve, but maybe this could help https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3

Answer (score 1):

You could also use reduce:

```
from functools import reduce

def double_letters(string):
    return bool(reduce(lambda x, y: not(x is y) and x and y, string))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if word1 != word2:
```

Here you are always comparing the words, and the words are not being updated in your loop. You should compare the characters at index1 and index2. Namely word1[index1] and word2[index2]

Comment: This is closer to the solution but still makes no sense as we don't know what OP wants `word1` and `word2` to be. Indeed, OP's script contains invalid code.

Comment: Indeed! The script is a mess from start to the end. I just wanted to give some clue to the OP as they stated that they are new to the language, so giving the complete solution wouldn't benefit their learning process.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regex ?

```
m = re.search(r"(.)\1{1,}", 'error')
m.group(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with sets by intersecting the list of character,position pairs with the list of character,position+1 pairs.  These pairs can be obtained using the enumerate() funciton:

```
def doubles(S):
    return any(set(enumerate(S))&set(enumerate(S,1)))

print(doubles("akdgjg"))     # False
print(doubles("dkjhfkddhk")) # True
```

A more efficient way would be to use zip() to access each letter with its successor and compare them together:

```
def doubles(S):
    return any(a==b for a,b in zip(S,S[1:]))
```